# What is the advantage of reseting password via OTP over reset link?

Tags: api, forgot-password, one-time-password, reset-password

This is basically a suggestion type of question. I have a scenario where we have to create an API endpoint to reset the password. I want to use OTP. But my senior suggests that we can send a reset link to the user's email ID. Can anyone give some strong points that what are the pros and cons of **OTP vs reset-link**?

And also I try to find some links regarding for this. And I'm not able to do so. Can you please provide some links also? If possible.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You want to build mobile app or website?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur Web app and we have a same build for mobile too

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148862/why-are-one-time-password-reset-links-safer-than-one-time-passwords

Comment: Hi @MuhammadDyasYaskur, Can you post it as a answer?